# Laravel: How to pass radio button value to controller and update?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update customer order status at admin panel. How to pass the radio button value to the controller using form.

Blade file

```
 <form action="{{url('vendor/orderstatus-update/' .$order->id)}}" method="POST" >
            {{ csrf_field() }}

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Order Status</h4>
                <div class="form-group">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="radio" name="order_status" id="Pending" value="Pending" > Pending<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="order_status" id="Processing" value="Processing" > Processing<br>              
                    <input type="radio" name="order_status" id="Delivery" value="Delivery" > Out For Delivery<br>              
                    <input type="radio" name="order_status" id="Cancelled" value="Cancelled" > Cancelled<br>                               
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

               </div>

              </form>
```

Below code is the function I write in controller

```
 public function updateOrderStatus(Request $request,$orderId){
    
         $orders=Order::where('order_id',$orderId)->find();
        $orders->update(['order_status'=>$request['order_status']]);
         return response()->json(['status'=>true],200);
}
```

[order table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ivH8.png)
The error that I get is:
{"success":false,"message":"A non well formed numeric value encountered"}

Any solution to fix this?

Comment: show routes and blade code also instead of image

Comment: do something like this `request('order_status')`

Comment: I think it's because you are using `->find()` without arguments. Try just `Order::where('order_id', $orderId)->update(['order_status' => $request->order_status])`.

Comment: Also note that in the form action you are using `$order->id`, but in the controller you are trying to find the record by `order_id` atributte.

Comment: @porloscerros after i change 'order_id' to 'id', the error become {"success":false,"message":"Function name must be a string"}

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know your table structure to help you with that. My second comment was just an observation. The query in my first comment doesn't work? Which is the primary key on your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
public function updateOrderStatus(Request $request,$orderId)
{
  try
  {
    $inputs = $request->all();
    $orders = Order::where('order_id', $orderId)->find();
    $orders->update(['order_status' => $inputs['order_status']]);
    return response()->json(['status' => true], 200);
  } catch (\Throwable $th) { dd($th->__toString()); }
}
```